# Selection is not possible when UICollectionView is nested in UITableVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios6, uicollectionview

I have a `UITableView` where each cell contains a `UICollectionView`.

I can scroll the `UITableView` vertically and scroll the nested `UICollectionView` horizontally, however I *cannot* select a `UICollectionViewCell` in the `UICollectionView`.

Selection is disabled in the `UITableView`, and enabled (the default state) in the `UICcollectionView`.

The `UICollectionView's` `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` is simply never called.

Comment: Is the UICollectionViewDelegate set?

Comment: Does the cell in the collection view present any tap response (like dimming or something like that)? Maybe `UITableView`'s cell is canceling the collection view's taps.

Comment: did you find a fix for this John?

Comment: Did you find a solution to make it work? Its always a problem combining horizontal and vertical scrolling because each `UIScrollView` has its own behaviour and together they are not so responsive anymore, I am interested in the solution!

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to solve this was to add a tap gesture recognizer to the cell to handle the tap manually, rather than rely on the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` which does not get called:

**Swift**

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "cellTapped:")
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
cell.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

**Objective-C**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellTapped:)];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

You can now handle the cell being tapped in the `cellTapped:` method, and you can get the reference to the cell that was tapped via `tapRecognizer.view`.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this working so I figured I'd share my solution with you guys.

After setting up the necessary delegates and datasources for the `UITableView` and nested `UICollectionView` you can make your `UICollectionView` the first selectable view like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    ...
    [tableViewCell bringSubviewToFront:tableViewCell.yourCollectionView];
    return cell;
}
```

This will make the `UICollectionView`  the first thing that's selectable via delegate

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Any other part of the view will be selected using the `UITableView` delegate

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

All the views that you have in a custom `UITableViewCell` should be layouted with respect to the `contentView`. So always add them as a subview to `contentView` and selection should work.

```swift
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let view = UIView()
        contentView.addSubview(view)

        // layout
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In viewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!{
        didSet{
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: TableViewCell.cellId)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

In TableViewCell File

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let cellId = "TableViewCell"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!  {
        didSet{
            collectionView.delegate = self
            collectionView.dataSource = self
            collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.cellId)
        }
    }
    

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}


extension TableViewCell : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.labelThing.text = "samples text"
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Hello world")
    }
}
```

In CollectionView File

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    static let cellId = "CollectionViewCell"

    @IBOutlet weak var labelThing: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

my first instinct is that the gesture recognizers between the two views may be conflicting

more specifically, the UITableView GRs for a tap may be preventing the UICollectionView GRs from receiving touches

Answer (score -1):

first plz check you have provided necessary data source and delegates. 
Then if you are using the collection view on specific number of table view cells you can directly put on in prototype cell. Please make sure your cell is with proper limits (width)

Answer (score -1):

Try to disable `delaysContentTouches` for `tableView` and make sure that `delegate` for your collection views are set correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I have tested both with storyboard and programatically, and it is working as expected. I receive collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: or tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath depending on the tapped area. It seems that, at least in newer SDKs (mine is 11.4), it is fixed.

Answer (score -3):

this shouldn't be a problem at all! no custom gesture recognizers needed. no need to disable the tableview's selection.

be sure to:

1. setup your tableview in storyboard or code and set its datasource and delegate
2. in cellforrowatindexpath after dequeueing a tableviewcell get a reference to the corresponding collectionview and set its (the collectionviews) datasource and delegate
3. implement the tableviews and collectionviews delegate didselect methods and log their calls out to see it works

i just implemented a small example project before i wrote that answer to be sure there is no problem. i can upload it if it still does not work for you!

good luck!